# Displaying Multiple Points And Drilldown Data in Highmaps

Tags: jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I used the example given in this post ( [Displaying Points And Drilldown Data in Highmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036951/displaying-points-and-drilldown-data-in-highmapshttp://)
)
it works fine if you have a drilldown series with a single point but if you have more then one

```
 tempSeries = chart.addSeries({
                            id: 'points',
                            type: 'mappoint',
                            name: 'Store Data',
                            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
                            data: [{
                                name: 'Point 1',
                                lat: 40.0633,
                                lon: -88.2498
                            },{
                                name: 'New York',
                                lat: 40.730610,
                                lon: -73.935242 
                            }

                            ]
                        });
```

[see my updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MONTHERZ/3se9q3uq/52/) when you click on Illinois you will get New York point with it.

is it possible to display only the points in the same state (when you click on Illinois you get only Illinois points)?

Comment: Why you want to add all of the points on your drilldown? Couldn't you just add points that are in state (for example add an arrays of points for specific states and load them on your drilldown)? I don't think there is a simple solution for your issue. You can ask for it on Highcharts uservoice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: yes that will be an easy thing to do but actually my scope is 5 states all of them have at least one location  :)